# How to type JSON object with number/boolean pairs

Tags: typescript

I have an object  that looks like this :

```
myObj = {
 1:true,
 2:false,
 3:true,
 5:true,
 7:false
}
```

I would like to know how I can type this in Typescript.

I have tried a coupld of things for example :

```
myObj: {{number: boolean}}
myObj: {[number: boolean]}
```

but they don't seem to work.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write it as such:

```js
myObj: Record<number, boolean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the "Record" utility type

```
myObj: Record<number,boolean> = {
 1:true,
 2:false,
 3:true,
 5:true,
 7:false
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dynamic object which only takes `number` as key & `boolean` as value

```
const obj: {[key:number]:boolean} = {1:true};
```

or can use typescript's builtin utility type `Record`

see the docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype

```
const obj: Record<number, boolean> = {1: true}
```